# Kafka Streams - store not created

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm going to calcolate an average with kafka streams. So i do a stateful operation, the aggregate, that need to create a state store, but this dose not happens.

Here the function for the average:

```
private void average () {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> source = 
                builder.stream(this.topicSrc);

        KStream <String, Double> average = source
                .mapValues(value -> createJson(value.toString()))
                .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(this.variable, value.getNumberValue(this.pathVariable, this.variable)))
                .groupByKey( Serialized.with(
                        Serdes.String(),
                        Serdes.String()))
                .aggregate (
                        () -> new Tuple(0, 0),
                        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) ->  new Tuple (aggValue.occ + 1, aggValue.sum + Integer.parseInt(newValue)),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new MySerde()))
                .mapValues(v -> v.getAverage())
                .toStream();

        average.to(this.topicDest, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));
        KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        stream.start();

    }
```

here the exception:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: base state directory [/tmp/kafka-streams] doesn't exist and couldn't be created
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:658)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:628)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:538)
    at it.imolinfo.sacmi.processor.Streamer.average(Streamer.java:167)
    at it.imolinfo.sacmi.processor.Streamer.run(Streamer.java:180)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: base state directory [/tmp/kafka-streams] doesn't exist and couldn't be created
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.<init>(StateDirectory.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.<init>(KafkaStreams.java:656)
    ... 5 more
```

The problem is that dose not exists the base directory but i want that kafka stream create the directory if neccessary.

--- EDIT -----
I have notice that if i have 1 processor that make the average for a variable there is no problem, but if i have 2 processors yes.

Configuration file for 1 processor:

```
 type->streamer
 number->1
 subtype->average
 variabli->payload:T_DUR_CICLO
 topicSrc->m0-tempi
 topicDest->average
 application.id->stream0
 bootstrap.servers->localhost:9092
 schema.registry.url->http://localhost:8081
 default.key.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
 default.value.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
```

configuration file for 2 processors:

```
type->streamer
number->1
 subtype->average
 variabli->payload:T_DUR_CICLO
 topicSrc->m0-tempi
 topicDest->average
 application.id->stream0
 bootstrap.servers->localhost:9092
 schema.registry.url->http://localhost:8081
 default.key.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
 default.value.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde

type->streamer
number->1
 subtype->average
 variabli->payload:HMI_TEMP_E1
 topicSrc->m0-temperature
 topicDest->average
 application.id->stream1
 bootstrap.servers->localhost:9092
 schema.registry.url->http://localhost:8081
 default.key.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
 default.value.serde->io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde
```

now i start the processor:

```
private void loadStreamer (Tuple t){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(t.getNumber());
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i ++) {
        String[] splitted = t.getVariables()[0].split(":");
        Streamer s = new Streamer (t.getSubType(), t.getTopicSrc(), t.getTopicDest(), splitted[0], splitted[1], t.getProp());
        Thread th = new Thread (s);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

the type Tuple contain the information of the configuration file.
the number in the for cicle is the number present in the configuration file. in this case is 1 but i can do more instance of the same process for a foult tolerance.

The Streamer:

```
    public class Streamer implements Runnable{


    private final String topicSrc;
    private final String topicDest;
    private final String variable;
    private final String pathVariable;
    private final String type;
    private final Properties props;

 public Streamer (String type, String topicSrc, String topicDest, String pathVariable, String variable, Properties props) {
        this.type = type;
        this.topicSrc = topicSrc;
        this.topicDest = topicDest;
        this.variable = variable;
        this.pathVariable = pathVariable;
        this.props = props;
    }

private void average () {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> source = 
                builder.stream(this.topicSrc);

        KStream <String, Double> average = source
                .mapValues(value -> createJson(value.toString()))
                .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(this.variable, value.getNumberValue(this.pathVariable, this.variable) + ":" + value.getStringValue("timestamp")))
                .groupByKey( Serialized.with(
                        Serdes.String(),
                        Serdes.String()))
                .aggregate (
                        () -> new Tuple(0, 0, ""),
                        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) ->  new Tuple (aggValue.occ + 1, aggValue.sum + Integer.parseInt(newValue.split(":")[0]), newValue.split(":")[1]),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), new MySerde()))
                .mapValues((key, value) -> new AverageRecord (key, value.getDate(), value.getAverage()))
                .mapValues(v -> v.getAverage())
                .toStream();

        average.to(this.topicDest, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));
        KafkaStreams stream = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        stream.start();
    }

 public void run()  {
        switch (this.type) {
            case "average":
                average();
                break;
            case "filter":
                filter();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("type not valid " + this.type);
            break;
    }
```

So i have 2 thread with 2 Streamer object that exec the average function.
the only different from 2 streamer is the variable to calculate the average.

I'm creating the process in wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be the permission issue. Kafka Stream application will create the state dir if it has permission to write in the given path.

`/tmp` directory should have write permission for the user which is running the application.

Comment: No i have run "sudo chmod 777 /tmp" and i receive the same exception

Comment: Please make sure you add permission for recursive "-R".

Comment: yes i've add the "-R" flag but i receive the same error.. i' have seen that if i have 2 instance of the processors that make the average for 2 different variable i have the error, while if i have only one processor i havn't the error

Answer (score 1):

Add a different `state.dir` configuration for each stream rather than the default one. Something like

```
# stream1
...
state.dir=/tmp/stream1/kafka-stream

# stream2
...
state.dir=/tmp/stream2/kafka-stream
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to execute `new File("/tmp/kafka-streams").mkdirs()` before starting your streams.
There is a race condition on KafkaStreams starter.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was just due to the disk being full (well, Kubernetes PVC) and increasing it fixed the issue. A bit cryptic!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by noticing the directory that it was trying to create via logs, creating that directory, and then giving that directory `777` permissions.